# How to rewrite an url with parameters in ASP.NET/C# using web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, web-config, url-rewriting

I am creating an asp.net web application and there I want it to work with or without file extension in the url

**As an example Lets say this is our url**
localhost:8080/Login.aspx?something=1

**I want it to work when user enters either**
localhost:8080/Login?something=1
 **OR** 
localhost:8080/Login.aspx?something=1

I did somethign like this

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite with .aspx" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.+)(\?(.+)$|\#(.+)$|$)"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx{R:2}"/>
    </rule>  
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Sometime this works, but not at all.Does it effect all other urls in the page other than the url in the address bar?I have iframes in my site.Someone please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if u are using Net 4.0,which got a built-in URL Routing feature 
check [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx) article

i think it will help you